# Caching: wrong paths and pages are not expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sweeper

I've got problem with simple caching (ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.1.3, development environment):

development.rb:

```
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.cache_store = :file_store, 'tmp/cache'
    config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = 'public/cache'
```

sweeper:

```
class CacheSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Article, Photo, Advertisement
  def after_save(record)
    expire_home
  end

...

  private

...

  def expire_home
    expire_page(:controller => '/homes', :action => 'index')
  end

end
```

controllers:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  caches_page :index
  cache_sweeper :cache_sweeper

  def index
....
```

Pages are cached in right directory and actions triggers sweeper actions as they should, but pages are not expired and server is trying to get cached pages from default place.

```
cache: [GET /] miss
```

Any ideas why? Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong controller name and leading slash.  Try the following:

```
def expire_home
  expire_page(:controller => 'home', :action => 'index')
end
```

Comment: I've found advice to use slash, so i've added it. Thanks for help, but when I'm using 'home' as controller name, problem still occurs...

Answer (score 0):

expire_page expects the path of the route so for example the root url in a caches page you could do

```
expire_page "/"
```

Also, to get your web server to look into the right place you need to configure a rewrite rule in apache or nginx to look in the cache directory.

Comment: Still the same. I'm using webrick and working on localhost. When I got defined path to cache (just like in my question), server can't find it. When I'm using default one - finding cached page works. Expiring still fails in both cases.